# Trouble with the lids of cylinders

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm having trouble making, and meshing cylindical-like objects. In both cases below I drew some vertices in the XZ plane and used screw to rotate. Except screw did not seem to like me having objects on the axis of rotation, so I deleted those nodes and filled. In the example on the left, I have filled with a cylinder. I then applied a metallic texture. Cool. Almost perfect, except you can see that remnant on the top that was rotated by screw has left radial sector marks.

[image]

So then I deleted the cylinder and deleted all of the faces along the top, and bottom, and replaced with GridFill. The mesh looked not so bad at all. But the texture [on right] is not better. Maybe worse. I tried adding a seam, which you can see here:

[image]

The unwrap did not look like what I was expecting. I thought I'd get two circles and a mesh, but all I get is a mesh[image]

Grrr....

Comment: what unwrap command did you use?  That grid looks like the default unwrapping of a cylinder, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your description, without the bevels, your model would look like this in x-ray mode:

[image: basic model without bevels]

If I select all and unwrap using the U key and selecting 'unwrap', I get this:

[image: resulting UV map.]

I think you might want to mark two more circles for unwrapping so the ledge area unwraps cleanly?

[image: additional seams]

unwraps to:

[image: new unwrap]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply @Marty. I'm pretty sure I was doing almost exactly as you say but I never got something close to the picture you have [did I mention that I am a complete noob :-)] I had clicked on Magic UV earlier, for better or worse - it hadnt helped, but maybe confused the correct way of doing things.

But then I found a different button to click and it worked perfectly. Instead of unwrap, I clicked  "Unwrap Constraints" and this beautiful plot immediately popped up
[image]